# Slack : Slack Web API Method :conversations. history method not working as expected when using Latest and oldest options

Tags: slack, slack-api

I am writing an slack app  for reading the messages from private channel and writing to database.
I use method **conversation.history** for this purpose.
My approach is

- Call the Slack api with parameters limit=100,channelId ,bot token and
  store the messages in database  along with the timestamp ts for
  message
- Fetch next 100 by calling method with prams as
  limit=100,channelid,bot token,oldest= ts (timestamp of oldest record inserted
  in database
  By the API documentation it says latest is default to value **now** .

In this case I should get next 100 records but I am getting nothing .

And I don't know how usually convert a date time like **12 Dec 2020
5:40:00 (12/03/2020)** to timestamp like **1607017252.113300**

I am using C# language for doing this whole work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be passing the oldest timestamp as the `latest` parameter in the next API call. (The Slack API would benefit from renaming "latest" to "newest".)

First call:

```
https://slack.com/api/conversations.history?token=TOKEN&channel=CHANNEL_ID&limit=100
```

Second call:

```
https://slack.com/api/conversations.history?token=TOKEN&channel=CHANNEL_ID&limit=100&latest=PREVIOUS_OLDEST_TS
```